# SMS Body not showing up in Google Sheets

Tags: sms, google-sheets, twilio

I am new to Twilio and am not a programmer so sorry if this is a dumb question.  I created a form in a Google sheet and copied to my Twilio account.  I can send a text message to the number and it adds a new timestamp line to the Google sheet but there is no other information like From or Body.  I used the tutorial instructions to create it.  How do I get the body of the text message to show up on the Google Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

One of the other evangelists on our team wrote some step-by-step- instructions that show you how to receive SMS messages into a Google Spreadsheet:

https://github.com/jpf/TwilioSheet#receive-twilio-sms-messages-in-a-google-spreadsheet

Hope that helps.

Devin

Comment: That is the tutorial that I used to create the Google Sheet.  I was very proud of myself that I was able to actually get it to communicate with a SMS text message by a Timestamp, but as my question stated, I am not receiving any of the body of my text in Google Sheet.

Comment: Hmmm..looks like Google might have changed stuff since that blog was posted.  I've asked the person who wrote the TwilioSheet instructions to take a look at see if they are still accurate.

Comment: Received this from Twilio SupportLooking at your Twilio Account, it looks like you've configured your Twilio phone number directly to the public link for your form. This is actually suppose to be configured to a URL that TwilioSheet creates for you (see step 11-14).

Since Google recently made changes to the way public form URL's are generated, an error is thrown when using TwilioSheet though. This appears to be a bug in the TwilioSheet app. I've contacted the owner of TwilioSheet to see if this is a bug they'll be able to fix.